# Typescript: Cannot find name 'Proxy'

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I need to declare a new variable with type Proxy, that is from ES6 specification:

```
myProxy: Proxy;
```

But I get the next error:

> Cannot find name 'Proxy'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the target set to `es2015` or are including the lib for `es2015` using the `lib` option, you can create a `Proxy`. The trick is that `Proxy` is not a type, it's a constructor. From the es2015 lib:

```
interface ProxyConstructor {
    revocable<T extends object>(target: T, handler: ProxyHandler<T>): { proxy: T; revoke: () => void; };
    new <T extends object>(target: T, handler: ProxyHandler<T>): T;
}
declare var Proxy: ProxyConstructor;
```

So to create a proxy you need to invoke the constructor:

```
let foo = new Proxy({ value: 0 }, {
    get: (v) => v.value * 2
});
```

The type of `foo` will be the same as the type of the target object.