# How can I listen to object changes using typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I have an object and I want to listen to changes in order to perform some actions, In ES6 I would have done something like that :

```
let members = {};
let targetProxy = new Proxy(members, {
    set: function (members, key, value) {
        console.log(key + " set to " + value);
        members[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Converted in typescript

```
const members = {};
let targetProxy: any = new Proxy(members, {
    set: function (members: any, key: string, value: string) {
        console.log(`${key} set to ${value}`);
        members[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
});
```

But the linter shows me this error message

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'Proxy'.
```

The terminal output :

[image: tsc output]

I have done some researches and I can't manage to find what's wrong.

As suggested, I changed my module parameter to ES6 instead of commonjs, nothing happens.
Complete output below

[image: Complete output error message typescript Proxy module]

and my package.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: Cannot find name 'Proxy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931825/typescript-cannot-find-name-proxy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project needs to have the TypeScript compiler options set to target ES2015 or later ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)). The command-line option would be `--target "ES2015"` (or `"ES2016"`, etc., or `"ESNext"` to target the latest proposed features).

---

Side note: `set` catches setting property values in the normal way, but not doing so via `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
const members = {};
let targetProxy = new Proxy(members, {
    set: function(members, key, value) {
        console.log(`${key} set to ${value}`);
        members[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
});
console.log("---- Notice no set trap fired:");
console.log(`targetProxy.foo: ${targetProxy.foo}`);
Object.defineProperty(targetProxy, "foo", {
  value: 1,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true
});
console.log(`targetProxy.foo: ${targetProxy.foo}`);
Object.defineProperty(targetProxy, "foo", {
  value: 2,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true
});
console.log(`targetProxy.foo: ${targetProxy.foo}`);
console.log("---- But it's fired for simple assignment:");
console.log(`targetProxy.bar: ${targetProxy.bar}`);
targetProxy.bar = 1;
console.log(`targetProxy.bar: ${targetProxy.bar}`);
targetProxy.bar = 2;
console.log(`targetProxy.bar: ${targetProxy.bar}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

To do that, you also need a `defineProperty` trap. (Note that both `set` and `defineProperty` will be triggered when setting a data property, assuming `set` allows the operation to proceed.)

(It also doesn't catch other changes, such as deleting properties, changing the prototype, etc.)

---

Side note 2: The `key` parameter to the `set` trap is `string | Symbol`, not just `string`.

Comment: I changed the parameters to ES6 but nothing seems to happen

Comment: why did you used "let" for "targetProxy" ? I thought "const" must be more appropriate.

Comment: @DaniloAkou - I just copied the code from the question, where you used `let`. Re your `package.json`, you've set the `module` option (sets what style of module output format to use), not the **`target`** option I pointed to above.